# На сколько эффективней использовать указатель в классе, чем последовательность get-обработка-set?

Tags: c++, ооп, указатели

Предположим, у нас есть мячик, цвет которого мы можем менять, и кошка, играющая с этим мячиком. Имея на руках указатель на мячик, мы можем "силой мысли" менять его цвет, не отбирая его у кошки. А без у указателя, чтобы поменять цвет мячика, нам придется "забрать" (вернее, даже не забрать, а клонировать) его у кошки, то есть применить последовательность get-обработка-set.

На сколько лаконичным и производительным получится код, если использовать указатель вместо последовательности get-обработка-set для обработки и изменения параметров класса? И какова гарантия, что не произойдет аварийного выхода из программы из-за обращения к несуществующему объекту?

Код с применением указателей:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Ball {
    public:
    string color;
};
class Cat {
    public:
    void takeBall(Ball *ball) {m_ball=ball;}
    Ball *giveBall() {return m_ball;}
    private:
    Ball *m_ball;
};

int main() {
    Ball *ball = new Ball();
    ball->color = "red";
    Cat cat;
    cat.takeBall(ball);
    cout<<cat.giveBall()->color<<endl; //red

    //...

    cat.giveBall()->color = "blue";
    // Имея на руках указатель на Мяч, можно поступить еще проще:
    ball->color = "blue";

    cout<<cat.giveBall()->color<<endl; //blue
    return 0;
}
```

Код без указателей:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Ball {
    public:
    string color;
};
class Cat {
    public:
    Ball getBall() {return m_ball;}
    void setBall(Ball ball) {m_ball=ball;}
    private:
    Ball m_ball;
};

int main() {
    Ball ball;
    ball.color = "red";
    Cat cat;
    cat.setBall(ball);
    cout<<cat.getBall().color<<endl; //red

    //...

    Ball catsBall = cat.getBall(); // get
    catsBall.color = "blue";       // обработка
    cat.setBall(ball);             // set

    cout<<cat.getBall().color<<endl; //blue
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Kromster , под эффективностью я понимаю лаконичность кода и скорость работы программы, под безопасностью - гарантию, что не произойдет аварийное завершение программы из-за обращения к несуществующему объекту.

Comment: Дело в том, что  в любом случаи  ваш подход ошибочный, потому что по вашему кошка может, например, менять цвет мяча. Как вы в жизни это представляете?...

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вам не знакомы концепции RAII (в частности умных указателей) и ссылок. Оба варианта просто ужасны и так делать не надо.

Comment: С указателями более очевидно (без изучения кода классов), какие данные **на самом деле** вы меняете.